# I am unable to use my view controller as a table data source

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uitableview

I am very new to XCode and I am trying to populate data into a table view that is a subview of a view controller. But I keep getting a runtime error and I cannot figure out why. Please help.

First thing I did was create the view in the storyboard, sized it, and left it as a Dynamic Prototypes table.

I then control-click dragged the table onto my View Controller class, and as expected it created a property:

```
@interface FAViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;

@end
```

Notice that I added the UITableViewDataSource Protocol. I then declared this class as the data source:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTable.dataSource= self;
}
```

Finally, I implemented the required required methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.myTable]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
```

When I run the app, it takes me to this piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([FAAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and says signal SIGBART. I hope I have provided all the relevant info. If not, please let me know.

Comment: If you look in the debugger when it crashes, it should print out some more information about the problem. If there is no output, you might have to press the continue button a couple of times to get it.

Comment: does your cell really have a cell identifier?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Try:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

On the first example, when you say " UITableViewCell *cell = nil;", you are saying the object pointer isn't pointing to anything and then the error occurs when you try to use this object. On the example i gave, you are avoiding this to happen.

Comment: and whats the difference between those?

Comment: On the first one, you are saying cell is nil and then trying to use something that doesn't "exist". Another solution would be this:

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

Comment: No one needs that with iOS6.. the method in your answer (actually both methods in your original answer) ensure that cell is not nil.

Btw: There is no difference in the first and the second version... except for the number of lines

Comment: scollaco, your second suggestion worked, but not the first one. Not sure why though. But thanks.

Comment: I tested before in an example and worked. Maybe I wasn't so clear on my explanation. Could you try to vote up, please? :)